# Cron Daemon - LibClamAV errors

Tags: debian, permissions, email, mysql, clamav

I have been receiving since a long time following mails:

```
From: Cron Daemon <root@autisticstory.net>
Subject: Cron <root@cloud-vps> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / &&
run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
To: root@autisticstory.net

/etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily:
Starting a daily scan of / directory.
 Amount of data to be scanned is 4.4G.
LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits -
only scanning 27262976 bytes
LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits -
only scanning 27262976 bytes
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4072 bytes @
offset 24, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4051 bytes @
offset 45, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4073 bytes @
offset 23, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4067 bytes @
offset 29, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @
offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @
offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4091 bytes @
offset 5, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4092 bytes @
offset 4, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4090 bytes @
offset 6, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4093 bytes @
offset 3, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4092 bytes @
offset 4, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @
offset 2, got 0

[...]

WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/jbd2/uevent: Permission denied
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for
'/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

Can you tell me how to fix these errors? I have Apparmor disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the password issue at the bottom of that email. The script is unable to access your MySQL server.

```
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/jbd2/uevent: Permission denied
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for
'/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

Specifically this:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Try logging into your MySQL DB that's locally on this server and verify the username/password work as expected. Then make sure that you can use `mysqladmin` to do the same as this CRON is attempting to do.